# Ios keyboard freezes when using textformfield while connected to vscode

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, visual-studio-code

here is the minimal reproduction of the code, The same code runs fine on Android, xcode but when running it with vscode , there is the keyboard freezing issue making the whole app crash after a while.
when i reopen the app without connecting it to debug or mac, the keyboards work fine its just when its connected and running with vscode.
vscode freezes too

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;
  TextEditingController textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Container(
          decoration:
              const BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 70, 64, 61)),
          height: 90,
          width: 1200,
          child: Row(children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
                    }),
                child: const Text(
                  'Click me',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ))
          ])),
      Expanded(
          child: Stack(children: [
        const Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 670,
              width: 1350,
            )),
        if (_isExpanded)
          Positioned(
              top: -30,
              left: 135,
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                            _isExpanded = false;
                          }))
                ]),
                Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 400,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {}),
                          controller: textFieldController,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          style: const TextStyle(decorationColor: Colors.black),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)))),
                        )))
              ]))
      ]))
    ]));
  }
}
```

flutter doctor

```
pannam@pannams-MacBook-Pro fly_nepal % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.17.6/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/pannam/flutter. Consider adding
      /Users/pannam/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

IOS.  Version 13.7

this is the debug console

```
Xcode build done.                                           15.5s
(lldb) SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "trustStateForApplication:" in class "nil"
SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "trustStateWithTrustRequiredReasons:" in class "nil"
SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "trustState" in class "nil"
Checking for file at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AB415382-25BB-4FE0-A12D-62E4DF32CA1B/Library/Caches/flex-extract.signal
FLXX: Loaded patches from: /var/mobile/Library/Application Support/Flex3/patches.plist
SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "_handleDoubleTapGesture:" in class "nil"
SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "scaleButtonTapped:" in class "nil"
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:61183/C1CPBUAIkxg=/ws
[Common] _BSMachError: port 14b03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
[general] Connection to daemon was invalidated
```

what exactly are these in the debug?

```
SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "_handleDoubleTapGesture:" in class "nil"
SubstituteLog: Attempted to hook non-existant selector "scaleButtonTapped:" in class "nil"
```

Comment: Interesting question. Is there any way you can trim down that code snippet even more? This will make people more likely to take a closer look at this question. Also just to be sure - Did you try removing the app from the device and reinstalling?

Comment: yup trimmed it down ! done everything there is to do...